# WildFly does not run main class from custom added module

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-9

I have added on custom module to WildFly 9. The JAR file has one main class as below:

```
package com.demo;

public class Main {
    static{
        System.out.println("**********************This is from main static********************");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("**********************This is from main********************");
    }
}
```

The **`module.xml`** file has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.demo">
    <main-class name="com.demo.Main"/>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="Demo.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

I have manually copied both files under `wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\com\demo\main`. But when I start WildFly I can not see either of the `System.out.println` lines.

Then I added module using `jboss-cli` command and it has added modules under `wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\com\demo\main`. But still on start of WildFly I can not see any `System.out.println`.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you're trying to do?  I am positive that Wildlfy would not run a main() method.  There are examples of, for example, custom login modules to base your code on.  What are you trying to do in your module?

Comment: Please add more information about your use case.

Comment: I am trying to **register dataSource as JNDI** , these are **dynamic JNDI** which is used by my **5 application** which is deployed on same wildfly instance, These JNDI details are read from the Database